# Performance issue with too many open http sessions in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

we are using Jenkins Enterprise for a while now. 
Since the latest update it seems as if the performance dramatically decreased when having multiple http sessions open.

Our experiments showed that there seems to be a limit (varying but always between 10 and 30) of open http sessions that can be served well while adding even one more takes everything down. As soon as we are closing a few sessions everything is back to normal
CPU, Memory and IO on the master machine are OK.

Anyone else experienced this recently?

Tobias
(technical details: Hosting the master machine on a Windows Server 2003 box, same happens on Win7 and XP, running in JRE 1.7, Jenkins ver. 1.466.12.1 (Jenkins Enterprise by CloudBees 12.11))

Comment: Did you notice this change going between versions in the 1.466 series itself, or going between 1.466.x and say 1.447? I think it's worth opening a ticket, and perhaps providing the scripts you use for testing.

Answer (score 1):

This has been filed as [JENKINS-16474](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16474) and is under investigation.